# Recover Foreign keys

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Infrastructure.OBSModules(
OBSId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Infrastructure.OBS(Id) NOT NULL,
ModuleId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Infrastructure.Module(Id) NOT NULL,
Constraint PK_Infrastructure_OBS_Module Primary Key(OBSId,ModuleId)
)
Go
```

The above code is my code by which I created Infrastructure.OBSType table,but I deleted foreign keys manually  so I cant Insert any rows in my table.how can I recover those foreign keys?

Comment: Perhaps those other tables erroneously have a foreign key to this table; remove those foreign keys first. When a table decomposes an M:M relationship into two 1:M the 1 side should not have a foreign key to the M side

Comment: Note I say perhaps because you didn't actually post the exact error message you're getting, which is probably the single most useful piece of information you can give to another developer when you ask for their help

Comment: Could not drop object 'Infrastructure.OBSModules' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: I want to delete this table without deleting the other tables which have ref to this table

Comment: What FK constraint is it referenced by? In SSMS right click the table, choose View Dependencies and post a screenshot

Comment: This question has been edited massively since I first looked at it; you now appear to be claiming that deleting foreign keys from a table prevents inserting data into is, which is just plain false. A table with no FKs is the easies tthing in the world to insert data into because you dont have to look up any dependent values